# Running maven within docker - Name or service not known: Unknown host mvn

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins

I am running Maven within Docker as part of a Jenkins build and encountering a problem where maven seems to be unable to download any of the dependencies.

Whether I run this from Jenkins, or directly from the command line I get this error.  I have tried running the command as the root user, and as the jenkins user, but get the same result.

```
run -v "$(pwd)":/usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject/main -w /usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/workspace/MyProject/main maven mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

...produces the following output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< com.mycompany:myproject >--------------------------
[INFO] Building MyProject rolling
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: http://mvn/repo/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.2/maven-jar-plugin-2.2.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.571 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-12T15:24:53Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:2.2: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:pom:2.2 from/to central (http://mvn/repo): mvn: Name or service not known: Unknown host mvn: Name or service not known -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Your url to central looks a bit weird. Would expect something like https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.2/maven-jar-plugin-2.2.pom

Comment: Holy cow - how did I not notice that?  Wow.  That's a local alias within the network at my office that of course won't work anywhere else.  {Facepalm} - thanks for spotting that.  Man I feel embarrassed.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)